# Is it possible to remove date in the title page of Beamer

Tags: beamer, titles

I am using `\usetheme{Warsaw}`. It seems that it doesn't depend on the theme. Does anyone know how to remove the date in the title page?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`\date{}` should work in Beamer, too.